# Is MapReduce an architectural pattern?

Tags: architectural-patterns

For a documentary reseach: Architectural Patterns (ex MapReduce), I started by reading the MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters paper. the authors define MapReduce as "a programming model and an associated implementation for processing and generating large data sets". Can we consider that MapReduce is an architectural pattern? or a design pattern? Why?.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog)**

Comment: I'd suggest reading [Are design patterns essential for good code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/224945/40980) and [What if I will not use Software Design Patterns?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/219830/40980) and consider what a pattern is.

Comment: @MichaelT Thank You for your answer. the discussion " Are design patterns essential for good code?" is really helpful !

Comment: Honestly, why does it make a difference to know if MapReduce is called an architectural pattern, a design pattern, or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapReduce is a lot more than simply stringing together a Map and a Reduce operation.  It's about distributed computing, running operations on a cluster over a large data set.  It contains architecture for initiating, monitoring and coordinating operations on the cluster, as well as for restarting operations on a system that fails (which happens sometimes on a large cluster), etc.  It definitely counts as an architecture pattern, beyond what appears on the surface to be the core functionality.